# xlsxwriter / First column not aligning to the left

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy, xlsxwriter

Having an issue aligning the first column to the left. Not sure what's wrong here. The formatting seems to work for the top row.

I just want the first column's text to align to the left.

```
def export_to_xlsx(date):
    global df
    ## CREATE PD DATAFRAME
    all_mp_dict = scraper(date)
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_mp_dict)

    ## WORKSHEET FORMATTING (TOP ROW - YELLOW BG COLOR)
    workbook_loc = './mp_excel/mp_data_'+date+'.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(workbook_loc, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=date+'_raw')

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[date+'_raw']

    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        'valign': 'top',
        'fg_color': '#FFFF00',
        'border': 1})

    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num+1, value, header_format)

    ## WORKSHEET FORMATTING (FIRST COLUMN - ALIGN LEFT)
    a_format = workbook.add_format()
    a_format.set_align('left')

    worksheet.set_column('A:A', 100, a_format)

    ## TO_EXCEL
    writer.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the Excel column format isn't being applied to the first column of the dataframe is that Pandas has already applied a bold/centered format to the cell to highlight the index values. In Excel, and XlsxWriter, a cell format overrides a column format.

So you can chose to drop the index and add you own, with it's own format, in the same way you are overwriting the column headers.

Comment: Thanks. I did have the same problem with the header, and I found the code above which you reference to make it work. I couldn't get my head around how to do the same for the first column - esp as there's no df.rows?

Comment: You can use df.shape to get the row, col limits for the dataframe. An alternative approach would be to add an index column to the dataframe and then drop the automatic (and automatically formatted) index column from the Excel export: `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=date+'_raw', index=False)`

Comment: Worked great, thank you.